# Lined up circle, n points

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, graphical-output

Draw lines between every pair of distinct points for `n` points arranged in a circle, producing something like the below result. Shortest code (in bytes) wins! Your lines don't have to be transparent, but it looks better that way. The output must be a vector graphic, or be an image at least 600 pixels by 600 pixels (either saved to a file or displayed on the screen). To complete the challenge you must draw at least 20.

[image]

Comment: It'd be cool if you had to take in a number `n` and draw lines for `n` points.

Comment: I second this idea. Change it before someone gets the first answer.

Comment: @shooqie Then the title wouldn't make sense though, unless that can be edited by the mods?

Comment: Or you can make a new one

Comment: Actually looks like anyone can edit the title, should I propose that as a change or leave it as is?

Comment: I mean, it's up to the submitter what he will do. You should propose it as a change though.

Comment: I don't think changing 37 to an arbitrary `n` would add much to the challenge as I expect most solutions to work with any number anyway, especially because 37 is odd and hence there are no mirror symmetries.

Comment: @Laikoni Well I figured it'd be interesting to see different patterns by changing the number, but I guess you could just use other people's solutions and change the 37 to whatever you want yourself.

Comment: Your sample output is not a vector graphic; it's a JPEG raster graphic.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson "or be an image at least 600 pixels by 600 pixels"

Comment: Do we take `n` as input or just pick an arbitrary `n` over 20?

Comment: What is the minimum permitted radius of the circle, as a fraction of the image size?

Comment: [Somewhat related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/60621/8478)

Comment: At least 80%? I mean... why is that concern?

Comment: What `n` did you use for your example?

Comment: @Titus `37`, it was the initial challenge (check the question's revision history for more details)

Comment: Do we have to parametrize? Please clarify with `for a given n` (and rephrase or remove the last sentence) or with `for n>=20 of your choice` or explicitly allow both. Thanks.

Comment: For people interested in the mathematics behind this specific graph, check out [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) link on complete graphs.

Answer (score 26):

**Mathematica, 13 bytes**

```
CompleteGraph
```

[image: lined-up-circle-37-points]

Looks like this only fails to give a circular embedding for `n=4`, but the question states `n>=20`

Comment: ...and there was me trying to find the correct way to make a function to take `n` (I had the answer ready from the fixed 37) :(

Comment: Why is that a built in?! That language is crazy good at graphing.

Comment: @carusocomputing This function has nothing to do with "graphing" in the sense of plotting. Mathematica is also very good for [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) problems and having a built-in to generate a complete graph seems like the first thing I would add if I added support for graphs to my language. The only reason this function happens to be useful for this challenge is that complete graphs are by default rendered with all vertices arranged in a circle.

Comment: If you're gonna support graphs, you better have a built in complete graph function, IMO.

Comment: @carusocomputing Welcome to Mathematica, the language that has a built-in for every existing function. :-P

Comment: I was downloading NetLogo because I thought "multi-turtle will make short work of this!" then remembered you Mathematicans are using the grown-up version.

Answer (score 13):

## [MATL](https://matl.suever.net/?code=%3AG%2F4%2aJw%5E2Z%5E%21XG&inputs=21&version=19.5.1), <s>16</s> 14 bytes

As I'm not terribly fluent with MATL I expect that this is somewhat more golfable. (Would be nice to at least beat Mathematica :-) I.e. the the flip `w` is not optimal, it could probably be avoided...

```
:G/4*Jw^2Z^!XG
```

[Test it Online!](https://matl.suever.net/?code=%3AG%2F4%2aJw%5E2Z%5E%21XG&inputs=21&version=19.5.1) (Thanks @Suever for this service, thanks @DrMcMoylex for -2 bytes.)

Explanation (for `N=3`):

```
  :               Generate Range 1:input:       [1,2,3]
   G/             Divide By the first input     [0.333,0.666,1]
     4*           Multiply by 4                 [1.33,2.66,4.0]
       Jw^        i ^ (the result so far)       [-0.49+ 0.86i,-.5-0.86i,1.00]
                  (This results in a list of the n-th roots of unity)
          2Z^     Take the cartesian product with itself (i.e. generate all 2-tuples of those points)
             !XG  Transpose and plot
```

It is worth noting that for generating the N-th roots of unity you can use the formula `exp(2*pi*i*k/N)` for `k=1,2,3,...,N`. But since `exp(pi*i/2) = i` you could also write `i^(4*k/N)` for `k=1,2,3,...,N` which is what I'm doing here.

[image]

Comment: You can change `XH:H` to `:G`

Comment: Aaah I forgot about `G` thank you very much!

Answer (score 13):

### [PICO-8](http://www.lexaloffle.com/pico-8.php), 131 bytes

I wasn't really sure if I'd be breaking any rules, but I did it anyway!

**Golfed**

```
p={}for i=0,19 do add(p,{64+64*cos(i/20),64+64*sin(i/20)})end for x in all(p)do for y in all(p)do line(x[1],x[2],y[1],y[2])end end
```

**Ungolfed**

```
points={}

for i=0,19 do 
  x=64+64*cos(i/20)
  y=64+64*sin(i/20)
  add(points,{x,y})
end

for x in all(points) do
  for y in all(points) do
    line(x[1],x[2],y[1],y[2])
  end
end
```

[image: 128x128 madness]

PICO-8 is a Lua based fantasy console with a native resolution of **128x128.** I made the circle as big as I could...

Answer (score 9):

## Mathematica, 42 bytes

Creates a set of 37 points arranged in a circle, and then draws lines between all possible subsets of two points. Someone posted a shorter answer that takes advantage of CompleteGraph, but I believe this is the shortest one aside from those relying on CompleteGraph.

```
Graphics@Line@Subsets[CirclePoints@37,{2}]
```

[image]

Comment: There's no need to avoid drawing lines from a point to itself, so you could save 3 bytes by using `Tuple`. You also need to update this to accept arbitrary `n`, but conveniently that won't cost you any bytes.

Comment: Meant to say `Tuples`

Answer (score 9):

## HTML + JS (ES6), 34 + <s>177</s> <s>164</s> 162 = 196 bytes

Using the [HTML5 Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API).

[See it on CodePen](http://codepen.io/darrylyeo/pen/xRpXYM).

```js
f=n=>{with(Math)with(c.getContext`2d`)for(translate(S=300,S),O=n;O--;)for(rotate(a=PI*2/n),N=n;N--;)beginPath(stroke()),lineTo(0,S),lineTo(sin(a*N)*S,cos(a*N)*S)}


/* Demo */
f(20)
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=600 height=600>
```

*-13 bytes*: Removed `closePath()`, moved `stroke()` inside `beginPath()`

*-2 bytes*: Defined variable `a` inside `rotate()`

Answer (score 8):

## Java, <s>346</s> <s>338</s> <s>322</s> 301 Bytes

This solution works for all `n>1`, even though the original post didn't require that, it does.

My favorite is `n=5`, don't ask why, also, if you want a cooler GUI, use:

`int a=Math.min(this.getHeight(),this.getWidth())/2;`

In place of the hard-coded 300, it'll use the width or height of the frame as the diameter.

*Saved 8 bytes thanks to Shooqie.*
*Saved 21 bytes thanks to Geobits.*

```
import java.awt.*;void m(final int n){new Frame(){public void paint(Graphics g){Point[]p=new Point[n];int a=300;for(int i=1;i<n+1;i++){p[i-1]=new Point(a+(int)(a*Math.cos(i*2*Math.PI/n)),a+(int)(a*Math.sin(i*2*Math.PI/n)));for(int j=0;j<i;j++){g.drawLine(p[i-1].x,p[i-1].y,p[j].x,p[j].y);}}}}.show();}
```

Output for `n=37`:

[image]

Comment: You can drop `Frame x=` and `final` (I think?)

Comment: @shooqie oops, `Frame x` was from another solution that involved a thread. You need the final though as it's an internal class reference to an external variable in the owning class.

Comment: It works just fine on my machine. BTW I think you can shave off some bytes by moving `int` declarations outside the `for` loops

Comment: @shooqie in Java 6 it's saying "Cannot refer to the non-final local variable n in an enclosing scope" at compile time.

Comment: It worked for me on Java 8, but after you edited your post I'm only getting white screen.

Comment: @shooqie fixed, made a dumb mistake.

Comment: All right, it still works for me without the `final` keyword, IDE only gives me a warning that `show()` is deprecated.

Comment: I'm having a problem getting this to work. When run as-is, it just gives me a tiny window, too small to actually show anything (or even the border-buttons like close/maximize).

Comment: When I expand the window, it show this: http://imgur.com/a/cl9oW Any ideas?

Comment: @Geobits yeah, I made a change that didn't pan out haha. Fixed.

Comment: You can also drop the `Panel` entirely and rearrange some stuff to save quite a bit: `import java.awt.*;void g(int n){new Frame(){public void paint(Graphics g){Point[]p=new Point[n];double f;for(int a=300,i=1,j;i<=n;i++){p[i-1]=new Point(a+(int)(a*Math.cos(f=i*2*Math.PI/n)),a+(int)(a*Math.sin(f)));for(j=0;j<i;)g.drawLine(p[i-1].x,p[i-1].y,p[j].x,p[j++].y);}}}.show();}`

Comment: (for Java 6 add that `final` back in I guess)

Comment: @geobits there's some other stuff in there that's not Java 6 friendly. If you want to use my answer and make a Java 8 answer that beats this, feel free :).

Comment: Huh, really? I think all I did (beside `final`) was drop the panel and rearrange variables. It works on my Java 6 as long as I add the final back in.

Comment: Please also post the ungolfed code so we can actually read it...

Answer (score 7):

### Python 2, <s>258</s> <s>235</s> 229 Bytes

```
import itertools as T,math as M
from PIL import Image as I,ImageDraw as D
s=300
n=input()
t=2*M.pi/n
o=I.new('RGB',(s*2,)*2)
for x in T.combinations([(s*M.cos(t*i)+s,s*M.sin(t*i)+s)for i in range(n)],2):D.Draw(o).line(x)
o.show()
```

Output for `n=37`
[image: n=37]

Comment: Wouldn't be `from PIL import*` shorter?

Comment: @RomanGräf PIL is a weird package, you can't `import *`, depending on how you install, you could skip the PIL and import Image/ImageDraw directly

Answer (score 6):

## Octave, <s>88</s> 69 bytes

```
N=input('');t=0:2*pi/N:N;k=nchoosek(1:N,2)';line(cos(t)(k),sin(t)(k))
```

Output for `N=37`:

[image]

Output for `N=19`:

[image]

Comment: Oh, I didn't even notice that there was already another Octave answer:)

Comment: Anyway, [beat ya](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/101847/24877) :-)

Comment: By a mile! My first thought was `gplot` too, but I didn't manage to make it short enough...

Answer (score 6):

### Perl, 229 bytes

It uses the same formula as most languages that don't have convenient builtin for this challenge (even if I didn't look at them to find it, but that's a fairly easy to find formula). So not very interesting, but there are usually not a lot of Perl answers to this kind of challenges, so I just wanted to propose one.

```
$i=new Imager xsize=>700,ysize=>700;for$x(1..$_){for$y(1..$_){$i->line(color=>red,x1=>350+300*cos($a=2*pi*$x/$_),x2=>350+300*cos($b=2*pi*$y/$_),y1=>350+300*sin$a,y2=>350+300*sin$b)}}$i->write(file=>"t.png")
```

And you'll need `-MImager` (9 bytes), `-MMath::Trig` (providing `pi`, 13 bytes), and `-n` (1 byte)  ==> + 23 bytes.

To run it :

```
perl -MImager -MMath::Trig -ne '$i=new Imager xsize=>700,ysize=>700;for$x(1..$_){for$y(1..$_){$i->line(color=>red,x1=>350+300*cos($a=2*pi*$x/$_),x2=>350+300*cos($b=2*pi*$y/$_),y1=>350+300*sin$a,y2=>350+300*sin$b)}}$i->write(file=>"t.png")' <<< 27
```

It will create a file named `t.png` which contains the image.

You'll need to install `Imager` though, but no worries, it's quite easy :

```
(echo y;echo) | perl -MCPAN -e 'install Imager'
```

(The `echo`s will configure you cpan if you've never used it before. (actually that will only work if your perl is recent enough, I think for most of you it will be, and I'm sorry for the others!)).

And the more readable version (yes, it's fairly readable for a Perl script!) :

```pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
use Imager;
use Math::Trig;
$i=Imager->new(xsize=>700,ysize=>700);
for $x (1..$_){
    for $y (1..$_){
    $i->line(color=>red,x1=>350+300*cos($a=2*pi*$x/$_), x2=>350+300*cos($b=2*pi*$y/$_),
         y1=>350+300*sin($a), y2=>350+300*sin($b));
    }
}
$i->write(file=>"t.png");
```

[image]

*-1 byte thanks to Titus.*

Comment: Does Perl require braces around single commands?

Comment: @Titus If you refer to the braces after the `for` loops, then yes, they are mandatory.

Comment: There´s a blank before `y2`. I bet you don´t need that. And can you write to STDOUT?

Comment: @Titus hmm indeed, thanks. I think I my terminal put a newline here so i didn't saw the space.

Answer (score 5):

## [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/), 92 bytes

```
a=polygon((0,0),(1,0),20)
sequence(sequence(segment(vertex(a,i),vertex(a,j)),j,1,20),i,1,20)
```

Each line is separately entered into the input bar. Here is a gif showing the execution:

[image: Execution]

**How it works**

The `polygon` command creates a 20-sided polygon, with the vertices of the baseline at `(0,0)` and `(1,0)`. The next command then iterates over each vertex of the polygon with index `i`, using the `sequence` and `vertex` commands, and for each vertex with index `i`, draws a line segment to every other vertex with index `j` using the `segment` command.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, <s>186</s> <s>184</s> 196 bytes

```
imagecolorallocate($i=imagecreate(601,601),~0,~0,~0);for(;$a<$p=2*M_PI;)for($b=$a+=$p/=$argv[1];$b>0;)imageline($i,(1+cos($a))*$r=300,$r+$r*sin($a),$r+$r*cos($b-=$p),$r+$r*sin($b),1);imagepng($i);
```

writes the image to STDOUT

**breakdown**

```
// create image with white background
imagecolorallocate($i=imagecreate(601,601),~0,~0,~0);

// loop angle A from 0 to 2*PI
for(;$a<$p=2*M_PI;)
    // loop angle B from A down to 0
    for($b=$a+=$p/=$argv[1];$b;)    // ($a pre-increment)
        // draw black line from A to B
        imageline($i,                           // draw line
            (1+cos($a))*$r=300,$r+$r*sin($a),   // from A
            $r+$r*cos($b-=$p),$r+$r*sin($b),    // to B ($b pre-decrement)
            1                                   // undefined color=black
        );
// output
imagepng($i);
```

**-12 bytes for fixed `n=20`**

Replace `$p=2*M_PI` with `6` (-8), `/=$argv[1]` with `=M_PI/10` (-2), and `$b>0` with `$b` (-2)

Using exact PI/10 doesn´t hurt. With `.3142`, the rounding errors from the parametrized version remained, but with `M_PI/10` they vanished and I can check `$b`(<>0) instead of `$b>0`. I could have saved two bytes with `.314`, but that would have off-set the points.

The limit `$a<6` is sufficiently exact for 20 points.

[image: exact PI graph]

**174 bytes for fixed `n=314`**

```
imagecolorallocate($i=imagecreate(601,601),~0,~0,~0);for(;$a<314;)for($b=$a++;$b--;)imageline($i,(1+cos($a))*$r=300,$r+$r*sin($a),$r+$r*cos($b),$r+$r*sin($b),1);imagepng($i);
```

Using 314 points results in a filled circle in that resolution (as do 136,140, every even number above that, and everything above 317).

Comment: Good answer, but it seems you've hardcoded 20 instead of taking that as input?

Comment: @Riking: True. But I can see no demand in the challenge for parametrizing it.

Answer (score 4):

### R, <s>127</s> 123 bytes

```
plot((e=cbind(sin(t<-seq(0,2*pi,l=(n=21)))*2,cos(t)*2)));for(i in 2:n)for(j in 1:i)lines(c(e[i,1],e[j,1]),c(e[i,2],e[j,2]))
```

**Produces :**
[image]

Nice axis' labels uh ?

*-4 bytes* thanks to @Titus !

Comment: Not shorter, but it could be faster with `for(i in 2:n){for(j in 1:i)...}`. Does `R`require the braces?

Comment: @Titus You're right ! And no, no braces needed there. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

### [NetLogo](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/) - 44 bytes

```
cro 20[create-links-to other turtles fd 20]
```

[image: NetLogo output]

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, <s>50 48 46</s> 45 bytes

```
@(N)gplot((k=0:2*pi/N:N)+k',[cos(k);sin(k)]')
```

This is an anyonmous function that plots the graph we're looking for.

Explanation:

`(k=0:2*pi/N:N)+k'` Makes a full `N+1 x N+1` adjecency matrix and simultaneously defines the vector `k` of angles, which we we use then for `[cos(k);sin(k)]'`, a matrix of coordinates where each graph node is positioned. `gplot` just plots the graph that we want.

For `N = 29` we get:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## BBC BASIC, 98 ascii characters

Tokenised filesize 86 bytes

```
r=600V.5142;29,r;r;:I.n:t=2*PI/n:F.i=1TOn*n:a=i DIVn*t:b=i MODn*t:L.r*SINa,r*COSa,r*SINb,r*COSb:N.
```

Dowload interpreter at http://www.bbcbasic.co.uk/bbcwin/bbcwin.html

There's nothing wrong with drawing every line twice, the appearance is identical :-P

**Ungolfed**

```
  r=600                              :REM Radius 600 units. 2 units per pixel, so 300 pixels
  VDU5142;29,r;r;                    :REM Set mode 20 (600 pixels high) and move origin away from screen corner
  INPUTn                             :REM Take input.
  t=2*PI/n                           :REM Step size in radians.
  FORi=1TOn*n                        :REM Iterate through all combinations.
    a=i DIVn*t                       :REM Get two angles a and b
    b=i MODn*t                       :REM by integer division and modlo
    LINEr*SINa,r*COSa,r*SINb,r*COSb  :REM calculate cartesian coordinates and draw line
  NEXT
```

**Output n=21**

This looks much better in the original rendering than in the browser.

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of the `LINE` function. Beats `DRAW`...

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, 36 bytes

```
@(n)plot(graph(ones(n),'Om'),'La','c')
```

This is an anoymous function that creates the plot.

```
@(n)                                     Define an anonymous fuction of 
               ones(n)                   Create an × matrix of ones
         graph(       ,'Om')             Create a graph object with that adjacency
                                         matrix, omitting self-loops
    plot(                   ,'La','c')   Plot the graph with a circular layout
```

Example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm surprised `graph` is not part of the bioinformatic toolbox...  didn't even know it existed... Nice :)

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES5)/SVG (HTML5), 181 bytes

```js
document.write('<svg viewBox=-1e3,-1e3,2e3,2e3><path stroke=#000 fill=none d=M1e3,0')
with(Math)for(i=37;--i;)for(j=37;j--;)document.write('L'+1e3*cos(a=i*j*PI*2/37)+','+1e3*sin(a))
```

Only works for prime numbers, such as the original suggestion of 37. You can halve (rounded up) the initial value of `i` to obtain a fainter image. You can also consistently adjust the `1e3,2e3` to other values to taste (I started with `300,600` but decided that it was too coarse).

Answer (score 1):

### QBasic 4.5, <s>398</s> 271 bytes

```
CLS:SCREEN 11:DEFSTR M-Z:DEFDBL A-L
INPUT"N",A:I=(360/A)*.0175:J=230
Q=",":FOR E=0 TO A
FOR F=E TO A
M=x$(COS(I*E)*J+J):N=x$(SIN(I*E)*J+J):O=x$(COS(I*F)*J+J):P=x$(SIN(I*F)*J+J):DRAW "BM"+M+Q+N+"M"+O+Q+P
NEXT:NEXT
FUNCTION x$(d):x$=LTRIM$(STR$(CINT(d))):END FUNCTION
```

The screen in QBasic can onl be 640x480, so the circle has a radius of only 230 px, unfortunately. Also, there's some artifacting because of float-to-int precision loss. Looks like this for `N=36`:
[image]

EDIT: I didn't need the storage, the type declaration and all the looping. Calculating all Carthesians from Polars in place is 50% cheaper in byte count...

Answer (score 1):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), <s>98</s> 94 bytes

```
$SCREEN 11|:i=6.3/a j=230[0,a|[b,a|line(cos(b*i)*j+j,sin(b*i)*j+j)-(cos(c*i)*j+j,sin(c*o)*j+j)
```

I've converted <s>my original QBasic answer</s> @LevelRiverSt 's answer to QBIC. I thought this would rely too heavily on functions that are not built into QBIC to be feasible, but as it turns out, it saves another 90 bytes. Substituting the
`DRAW` for `LINE` saves another 80 bytes. I knew I was forgetting something simple...

When run with a command line parameter of 36, it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Processing, 274 bytes (239 + `size` call and function call)

```
void d(int s){float a=2*PI/s,x=0,y=-400,m,n;float[][]p=new float[2][s];translate(400,400);for(int i=0;i<s;i++){m=x*cos(a)-y*sin(a);n=x*sin(a)+y*cos(a);x=m;y=n;p[0][i]=x;p[1][i]=y;for(int j=0;j<i;j++)line(p[0][j],p[1][j],p[0][i],p[1][i]);}}
void setup(){size(800,800);d(50);}
```

I honestly don't know why, but `setup` had to be on the second line. I used https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix to help me calculate the maths for rotation. This program calculates the points and pushes them to an array, with which we are using to draw lines.

Here is a picture of a polygon with 50 edges (the 100 edges one was almost completely black)

[image: 50 points]

You can add `stroke(0,alpha);` to have transparent edges, where `alpha` is the opacity of the line. Here's the same polygon with `alpha` of `20`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + Jelly + GraphViz, 52 characters, 52 or 63 bytes

Given that the programs in question disagree on which character encoding to use, the program is full of control characters. Here's what it looks like under `xxd`, in Latin-1 encoding (which represents each character in one byte):

```
00000000: 6a65 6c6c 7920 6520 2793 5213 636a 0c8e  jelly e '.R.cj..
00000010: 2d2d 59fe 9a3f 1d15 dc65 34d3 8442 7f05  --Y..?...e4..B..
00000020: 1172 80cf fb3b ff7d 277c 6369 7263 6f20  .r...;.}'|circo 
00000030: 2d54 7073                                -Tps
```

I couldn't actually get the program to run, though, without converting the input into UTF-8 for some reason (which would make it 63 bytes long). Logically it *should* work as Latin-1 – none of the characters are outside the range 0 to 255 – but I keep getting "string index out of range" errors no matter how I configure the character encoding environment variables. So this will have to be counted as 63 bytes unless someone can figure out a way to run it without re-encoding it.

The program might be slightly more readable if we interpret it in Jelly's encoding:

```
jelly e 'ƓRŒcj€⁾--Y“Ȥ?øßṇe4ạ⁴B¶¦×r°Ẇ»;”}'|circo -Tps
```

The program takes the number of points on standard input and outputs a PostScript image on standard output. (It can trivially be adapted to output in any format GraphViz supports by changing the `-Tps` at the end; it's just that PostScript has the shortest name. Arguably, you can save five characters by removing the `-Tps`, but then you get output in GraphViz's internal image format that nothing else supports, which probably doesn't count for the purposes of the question.)

Fundamentally, this is just a Jelly program that calls into GraphViz to do the drawing; however, Jelly doesn't seem to have any capabilities for running external programs, so I had to use bash to link them together. (This also means that it's cheaper to make Jelly request input from stdin manually; normally it takes input from the command line, but that would mean extra bytes in the bash wrapper.) `circo` will automatically arrange all the points it's asked to draw in a circle, so the Jelly code just has to ask it to draw a list of points, all of which are connected to each other. Here's how it works:

```
ƓRŒcj€⁾--Y“Ȥ?øßṇe4ạ⁴B¶¦×r°Ẇ»;”}
Ɠ                               read number from stdin
 R                              produce range from 1 to that number
                                (here used to produce a list with
                                that many distinct elements)
  Œc                            select all unordered pairs from that
      ⁾--                       a string consisting of two hyphens
    j€                          join each pair via the string
         Y                      join on newlines
                            ;   prepend (in this context)
          “Ȥ?øßṇe4ạ⁴B¶¦×r°Ẇ»    "graph{node[shape=point]"
                             ”} follow output with a "}" character
```

The use of Jelly lets us slightly compress the string that configures the GraphViz output via its built-in dictionary. The dictionary has `graph`, `node`, and `point`. Annoyingly, it doesn't have `shape` (it has `SHAPE`, but GraphViz is case-sensitive), so we have to encode that character-by-character.

Here's the output for input 21 (with a slight modification to the program to make it output in a format that can be uploaded to Stack Exchange):

[image: complete graph on 21 points]

Answer (score 0):

## PHP + HTML SVG, <s>316</s> 263 bytes

**Golfed version with hardcoded `n` points and no input `n` parameter:**

```
<svg height="610" width="610"><?for($i=1;$i<33;$i++){$x[]=300*sin(2*M_PI/32*$i)+305;$y[]=300*cos(2*M_PI/32)+305;}foreach($x as$j=>$w){foreach($y as$k=>$z){echo'<line x1="'.$x[$j].'" y1="'.$y[$j].'" x2="'.$x[$k].'" y2="'.$y[$k].'" style="stroke:red;"/>';}}?></svg>
```

**Previous golfed version with input parameter for `n` points, 316 bytes:**

```
<svg height="610" width="610"><?$n=$_GET[n];$d=2*M_PI/$n;$r=300;$o=305;for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++){$x[]=$r*sin($d*$i)+$o;$y[]=$r*cos($d*$i)+$o;}foreach($x as$j=>$w){foreach($y as$k=>$z){echo'<line x1="'.$x[$j].'" y1="'.$y[$j].'" x2="'.$x[$k].'" y2="'.$y[$k].'" style="stroke:rgba(0,0,0,.15);stroke-width:1;" />';}}?></svg>
```

Usage: save in a file and call from the browser:

```
http://localhost/codegolf/circle.php?n=32
```

Ungolfed version with input parameter for `n` points and CSS:

```
<style>
line {
    stroke: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    stroke-width:1;
}
</style>
<svg height="610" width="610">
<?php
$n=$_GET[n]; // number of points
$d=2*M_PI/$n; // circle parts
$r=300; // circle radius
$o=305; // offset x,y
for ($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++){
    $x[]=$r*sin($d*$i)+$o; // store x,y coordinates in array
    $y[]=$r*cos($d*$i)+$o;
}
foreach($x as $j => $w){ // iterate all x,y points and connect to each other
    foreach($y as $k => $z) {
        echo '<line x1="'.$x[$j].'" y1="'.$y[$j].'" x2="'.$x[$k].'" y2="'.$y[$k].'" />'."\n";   
    }
}
?>
</svg>
```

Couldn't attach a 32 points fully functional snippet because of the 30k characters limit for a single post. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

The attached snippet is limited to 18 points because of the 30k single post limit.

```css
line {
stroke: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
stroke-width:1;
}
```

```html
<svg height="610" width="610">
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="586.90778623577" x2="407.6060429977" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="586.90778623577" x2="497.83628290596" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="586.90778623577" x2="564.80762113533" y2="455" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="586.90778623577" x2="600.44232590366" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="586.90778623577" x2="600.44232590366" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="586.90778623577" x2="564.80762113533" y2="155" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="586.90778623577" x2="497.83628290596" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="586.90778623577" x2="407.6060429977" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="586.90778623577" x2="305" y2="5" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="586.90778623577" x2="202.3939570023" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="586.90778623577" x2="112.16371709404" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="586.90778623577" x2="45.192378864669" y2="155" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="586.90778623577" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="586.90778623577" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="586.90778623577" x2="45.192378864668" y2="455" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="586.90778623577" x2="112.16371709404" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="586.90778623577" x2="202.3939570023" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="586.90778623577" x2="305" y2="605" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="534.81333293569" x2="407.6060429977" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="534.81333293569" x2="497.83628290596" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="534.81333293569" x2="564.80762113533" y2="455" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="534.81333293569" x2="600.44232590366" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="534.81333293569" x2="600.44232590366" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="534.81333293569" x2="564.80762113533" y2="155" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="534.81333293569" x2="497.83628290596" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="534.81333293569" x2="407.6060429977" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="534.81333293569" x2="305" y2="5" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="534.81333293569" x2="202.3939570023" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="534.81333293569" x2="112.16371709404" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="534.81333293569" x2="45.192378864669" y2="155" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="534.81333293569" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="534.81333293569" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="534.81333293569" x2="45.192378864668" y2="455" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="534.81333293569" x2="112.16371709404" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="534.81333293569" x2="202.3939570023" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="534.81333293569" x2="305" y2="605" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="455" x2="407.6060429977" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="455" x2="497.83628290596" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="455" x2="564.80762113533" y2="455" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="455" x2="600.44232590366" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="455" x2="600.44232590366" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="455" x2="564.80762113533" y2="155" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="455" x2="497.83628290596" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="455" x2="407.6060429977" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="455" x2="305" y2="5" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="455" x2="202.3939570023" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="455" x2="112.16371709404" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="455" x2="45.192378864669" y2="155" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="455" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="455" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="455" x2="45.192378864668" y2="455" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="455" x2="112.16371709404" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="455" x2="202.3939570023" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="455" x2="305" y2="605" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="357.09445330008" x2="407.6060429977" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="357.09445330008" x2="497.83628290596" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="357.09445330008" x2="564.80762113533" y2="455" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="357.09445330008" x2="600.44232590366" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="357.09445330008" x2="600.44232590366" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="357.09445330008" x2="564.80762113533" y2="155" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="357.09445330008" x2="497.83628290596" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="357.09445330008" x2="407.6060429977" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="357.09445330008" x2="305" y2="5" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="357.09445330008" x2="202.3939570023" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="357.09445330008" x2="112.16371709404" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="357.09445330008" x2="45.192378864669" y2="155" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="357.09445330008" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="357.09445330008" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="357.09445330008" x2="45.192378864668" y2="455" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="357.09445330008" x2="112.16371709404" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="357.09445330008" x2="202.3939570023" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="357.09445330008" x2="305" y2="605" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="252.90554669992" x2="407.6060429977" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="252.90554669992" x2="497.83628290596" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="252.90554669992" x2="564.80762113533" y2="455" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="252.90554669992" x2="600.44232590366" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="252.90554669992" x2="600.44232590366" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="252.90554669992" x2="564.80762113533" y2="155" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="252.90554669992" x2="497.83628290596" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="252.90554669992" x2="407.6060429977" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="252.90554669992" x2="305" y2="5" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="252.90554669992" x2="202.3939570023" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="252.90554669992" x2="112.16371709404" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="252.90554669992" x2="45.192378864669" y2="155" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="252.90554669992" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="252.90554669992" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="252.90554669992" x2="45.192378864668" y2="455" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="252.90554669992" x2="112.16371709404" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="252.90554669992" x2="202.3939570023" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="600.44232590366" y1="252.90554669992" x2="305" y2="605" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="155" x2="407.6060429977" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="155" x2="497.83628290596" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="155" x2="564.80762113533" y2="455" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="155" x2="600.44232590366" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="155" x2="600.44232590366" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="155" x2="564.80762113533" y2="155" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="155" x2="497.83628290596" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="155" x2="407.6060429977" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="155" x2="305" y2="5" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="155" x2="202.3939570023" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="155" x2="112.16371709404" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="155" x2="45.192378864669" y2="155" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="155" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="155" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="155" x2="45.192378864668" y2="455" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="155" x2="112.16371709404" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="155" x2="202.3939570023" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="564.80762113533" y1="155" x2="305" y2="605" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="75.186667064307" x2="407.6060429977" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="75.186667064307" x2="497.83628290596" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="75.186667064307" x2="564.80762113533" y2="455" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="75.186667064307" x2="600.44232590366" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="75.186667064307" x2="600.44232590366" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="75.186667064307" x2="564.80762113533" y2="155" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="75.186667064307" x2="497.83628290596" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="75.186667064307" x2="407.6060429977" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="75.186667064307" x2="305" y2="5" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="75.186667064307" x2="202.3939570023" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="75.186667064307" x2="112.16371709404" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="75.186667064307" x2="45.192378864669" y2="155" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="75.186667064307" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="75.186667064307" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="75.186667064307" x2="45.192378864668" y2="455" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="75.186667064307" x2="112.16371709404" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="75.186667064307" x2="202.3939570023" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="497.83628290596" y1="75.186667064307" x2="305" y2="605" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="23.092213764227" x2="407.6060429977" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="23.092213764227" x2="497.83628290596" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="23.092213764227" x2="564.80762113533" y2="455" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="23.092213764227" x2="600.44232590366" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="23.092213764227" x2="600.44232590366" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="23.092213764227" x2="564.80762113533" y2="155" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="23.092213764227" x2="497.83628290596" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="23.092213764227" x2="407.6060429977" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="23.092213764227" x2="305" y2="5" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="23.092213764227" x2="202.3939570023" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="23.092213764227" x2="112.16371709404" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="23.092213764227" x2="45.192378864669" y2="155" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="23.092213764227" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="23.092213764227" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="23.092213764227" x2="45.192378864668" y2="455" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="23.092213764227" x2="112.16371709404" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="23.092213764227" x2="202.3939570023" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="407.6060429977" y1="23.092213764227" x2="305" y2="605" />
<line x1="305" y1="5" x2="407.6060429977" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="305" y1="5" x2="497.83628290596" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="305" y1="5" x2="564.80762113533" y2="455" />
<line x1="305" y1="5" x2="600.44232590366" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="305" y1="5" x2="600.44232590366" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="305" y1="5" x2="564.80762113533" y2="155" />
<line x1="305" y1="5" x2="497.83628290596" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="305" y1="5" x2="407.6060429977" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="305" y1="5" x2="305" y2="5" />
<line x1="305" y1="5" x2="202.3939570023" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="305" y1="5" x2="112.16371709404" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="305" y1="5" x2="45.192378864669" y2="155" />
<line x1="305" y1="5" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="305" y1="5" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="305" y1="5" x2="45.192378864668" y2="455" />
<line x1="305" y1="5" x2="112.16371709404" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="305" y1="5" x2="202.3939570023" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="305" y1="5" x2="305" y2="605" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="23.092213764227" x2="407.6060429977" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="23.092213764227" x2="497.83628290596" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="23.092213764227" x2="564.80762113533" y2="455" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="23.092213764227" x2="600.44232590366" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="23.092213764227" x2="600.44232590366" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="23.092213764227" x2="564.80762113533" y2="155" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="23.092213764227" x2="497.83628290596" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="23.092213764227" x2="407.6060429977" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="23.092213764227" x2="305" y2="5" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="23.092213764227" x2="202.3939570023" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="23.092213764227" x2="112.16371709404" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="23.092213764227" x2="45.192378864669" y2="155" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="23.092213764227" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="23.092213764227" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="23.092213764227" x2="45.192378864668" y2="455" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="23.092213764227" x2="112.16371709404" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="23.092213764227" x2="202.3939570023" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="23.092213764227" x2="305" y2="605" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="75.186667064307" x2="407.6060429977" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="75.186667064307" x2="497.83628290596" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="75.186667064307" x2="564.80762113533" y2="455" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="75.186667064307" x2="600.44232590366" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="75.186667064307" x2="600.44232590366" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="75.186667064307" x2="564.80762113533" y2="155" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="75.186667064307" x2="497.83628290596" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="75.186667064307" x2="407.6060429977" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="75.186667064307" x2="305" y2="5" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="75.186667064307" x2="202.3939570023" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="75.186667064307" x2="112.16371709404" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="75.186667064307" x2="45.192378864669" y2="155" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="75.186667064307" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="75.186667064307" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="75.186667064307" x2="45.192378864668" y2="455" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="75.186667064307" x2="112.16371709404" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="75.186667064307" x2="202.3939570023" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="75.186667064307" x2="305" y2="605" />
<line x1="45.192378864669" y1="155" x2="407.6060429977" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="45.192378864669" y1="155" x2="497.83628290596" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="45.192378864669" y1="155" x2="564.80762113533" y2="455" />
<line x1="45.192378864669" y1="155" x2="600.44232590366" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="45.192378864669" y1="155" x2="600.44232590366" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="45.192378864669" y1="155" x2="564.80762113533" y2="155" />
<line x1="45.192378864669" y1="155" x2="497.83628290596" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="45.192378864669" y1="155" x2="407.6060429977" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="45.192378864669" y1="155" x2="305" y2="5" />
<line x1="45.192378864669" y1="155" x2="202.3939570023" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="45.192378864669" y1="155" x2="112.16371709404" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="45.192378864669" y1="155" x2="45.192378864669" y2="155" />
<line x1="45.192378864669" y1="155" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="45.192378864669" y1="155" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="45.192378864669" y1="155" x2="45.192378864668" y2="455" />
<line x1="45.192378864669" y1="155" x2="112.16371709404" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="45.192378864669" y1="155" x2="202.3939570023" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="45.192378864669" y1="155" x2="305" y2="605" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="252.90554669992" x2="407.6060429977" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="252.90554669992" x2="497.83628290596" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="252.90554669992" x2="564.80762113533" y2="455" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="252.90554669992" x2="600.44232590366" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="252.90554669992" x2="600.44232590366" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="252.90554669992" x2="564.80762113533" y2="155" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="252.90554669992" x2="497.83628290596" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="252.90554669992" x2="407.6060429977" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="252.90554669992" x2="305" y2="5" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="252.90554669992" x2="202.3939570023" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="252.90554669992" x2="112.16371709404" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="252.90554669992" x2="45.192378864669" y2="155" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="252.90554669992" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="252.90554669992" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="252.90554669992" x2="45.192378864668" y2="455" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="252.90554669992" x2="112.16371709404" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="252.90554669992" x2="202.3939570023" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="252.90554669992" x2="305" y2="605" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="357.09445330008" x2="407.6060429977" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="357.09445330008" x2="497.83628290596" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="357.09445330008" x2="564.80762113533" y2="455" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="357.09445330008" x2="600.44232590366" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="357.09445330008" x2="600.44232590366" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="357.09445330008" x2="564.80762113533" y2="155" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="357.09445330008" x2="497.83628290596" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="357.09445330008" x2="407.6060429977" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="357.09445330008" x2="305" y2="5" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="357.09445330008" x2="202.3939570023" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="357.09445330008" x2="112.16371709404" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="357.09445330008" x2="45.192378864669" y2="155" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="357.09445330008" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="357.09445330008" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="357.09445330008" x2="45.192378864668" y2="455" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="357.09445330008" x2="112.16371709404" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="357.09445330008" x2="202.3939570023" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="9.5576740963376" y1="357.09445330008" x2="305" y2="605" />
<line x1="45.192378864668" y1="455" x2="407.6060429977" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="45.192378864668" y1="455" x2="497.83628290596" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="45.192378864668" y1="455" x2="564.80762113533" y2="455" />
<line x1="45.192378864668" y1="455" x2="600.44232590366" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="45.192378864668" y1="455" x2="600.44232590366" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="45.192378864668" y1="455" x2="564.80762113533" y2="155" />
<line x1="45.192378864668" y1="455" x2="497.83628290596" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="45.192378864668" y1="455" x2="407.6060429977" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="45.192378864668" y1="455" x2="305" y2="5" />
<line x1="45.192378864668" y1="455" x2="202.3939570023" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="45.192378864668" y1="455" x2="112.16371709404" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="45.192378864668" y1="455" x2="45.192378864669" y2="155" />
<line x1="45.192378864668" y1="455" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="45.192378864668" y1="455" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="45.192378864668" y1="455" x2="45.192378864668" y2="455" />
<line x1="45.192378864668" y1="455" x2="112.16371709404" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="45.192378864668" y1="455" x2="202.3939570023" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="45.192378864668" y1="455" x2="305" y2="605" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="534.81333293569" x2="407.6060429977" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="534.81333293569" x2="497.83628290596" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="534.81333293569" x2="564.80762113533" y2="455" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="534.81333293569" x2="600.44232590366" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="534.81333293569" x2="600.44232590366" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="534.81333293569" x2="564.80762113533" y2="155" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="534.81333293569" x2="497.83628290596" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="534.81333293569" x2="407.6060429977" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="534.81333293569" x2="305" y2="5" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="534.81333293569" x2="202.3939570023" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="534.81333293569" x2="112.16371709404" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="534.81333293569" x2="45.192378864669" y2="155" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="534.81333293569" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="534.81333293569" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="534.81333293569" x2="45.192378864668" y2="455" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="534.81333293569" x2="112.16371709404" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="534.81333293569" x2="202.3939570023" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="112.16371709404" y1="534.81333293569" x2="305" y2="605" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="586.90778623577" x2="407.6060429977" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="586.90778623577" x2="497.83628290596" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="586.90778623577" x2="564.80762113533" y2="455" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="586.90778623577" x2="600.44232590366" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="586.90778623577" x2="600.44232590366" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="586.90778623577" x2="564.80762113533" y2="155" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="586.90778623577" x2="497.83628290596" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="586.90778623577" x2="407.6060429977" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="586.90778623577" x2="305" y2="5" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="586.90778623577" x2="202.3939570023" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="586.90778623577" x2="112.16371709404" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="586.90778623577" x2="45.192378864669" y2="155" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="586.90778623577" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="586.90778623577" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="586.90778623577" x2="45.192378864668" y2="455" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="586.90778623577" x2="112.16371709404" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="586.90778623577" x2="202.3939570023" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="202.3939570023" y1="586.90778623577" x2="305" y2="605" />
<line x1="305" y1="605" x2="407.6060429977" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="305" y1="605" x2="497.83628290596" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="305" y1="605" x2="564.80762113533" y2="455" />
<line x1="305" y1="605" x2="600.44232590366" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="305" y1="605" x2="600.44232590366" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="305" y1="605" x2="564.80762113533" y2="155" />
<line x1="305" y1="605" x2="497.83628290596" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="305" y1="605" x2="407.6060429977" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="305" y1="605" x2="305" y2="5" />
<line x1="305" y1="605" x2="202.3939570023" y2="23.092213764227" />
<line x1="305" y1="605" x2="112.16371709404" y2="75.186667064307" />
<line x1="305" y1="605" x2="45.192378864669" y2="155" />
<line x1="305" y1="605" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="252.90554669992" />
<line x1="305" y1="605" x2="9.5576740963376" y2="357.09445330008" />
<line x1="305" y1="605" x2="45.192378864668" y2="455" />
<line x1="305" y1="605" x2="112.16371709404" y2="534.81333293569" />
<line x1="305" y1="605" x2="202.3939570023" y2="586.90778623577" />
<line x1="305" y1="605" x2="305" y2="605" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

## R, 108 bytes

```
plot(x<-cos(t<-seq(0,2*pi,l=21)),y<-sin(t),as=1);apply(expand.grid(1:21,1:21),1,function(e)lines(x[e],y[e]))
```

Could shave 5 bytes off if I got rid of argument `,as=1` which forces an aspect ratio of 1. Uses `expand.grid` to create a matrix with all possible pair of points, and uses `apply` to loop through it.

[image: N=21]

## R + igraph, 87 bytes

Another solution using package `igraph`.

```
library(igraph);plot(make_full_graph(21),layout=cbind(cos(t<-seq(0,2*pi,l=21)),sin(t)))
```

[image: N=21]